# linked list operations (core dumped)

Tags: c, linked-list

Recently I've been improving my programming skills by coding different data structures, and this is the very beginning!!!

Now I'm writing the linked list, but something annoyed happen and the trouble has been annoyed me for a long time since I am not quite sure about this error, 
Segmentation fault(core dumped), but I did know I made something wrong in the operation of memory.

link_list.h:

```
struct LINK_LIST {
  char *string;
  struct LINK_LIST *next;
}link_list;
```

==============================

link_list.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int init_link_list(struct LINK_LIST *new_link) {
  //char *new_string;
  int i;
  //new_string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * STRING_SIZE);
  new_link = (struct LINK_LIST *)malloc(sizeof(struct LINK_LIST));
  if (new_link==NULL) {
fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory!!!");
return ERROR;
  }
  //new_link->string = new_string;
  new_link->string = NULL;
  //new_link->next = NULL;

  return OK;
}
```

Here I defined the init operation, then the insert operation:

```
int insert(struct LINK_LIST *link, int pos, char *in) {
  int i;
  if (get_length(link)>=STRING_SIZE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Link list is full!!!");
    return ERROR;
  }
  else {
    if (pos < 0 || pos-1 > get_length(link)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid position");
      return ERROR;
    }
    else {
      i = 0;
      do {
          struct LINK_LIST *new_node;
          init_link_list(new_node);
          new_node->next = link->next;
          link->next = new_node;
          new_node->string = in;
          i += 1;
        } while(i<pos-1);
     }
 }
 return OK;
}
```

Comment: Your first job is to remove the `(struct LINK_LIST *)` cast on the right hand side of `=`.

Comment: You need to follow these guidelines: http://sscce.org/ Post the smallest failing test case you can make.

Comment: After `init_link_list(new_node);`, the pointer `new_node` is still uninitialized.

Comment: why is the pointer `new_node` still uninitialized? so I should initialize it by myself using `malloc`?

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug there :

```
struct LINK_LIST *new_node;
init_link_list(new_node);
```

In `init_link_list`, the value of the argument is modified :

```
new_link = (struct LINK_LIST *)malloc(sizeof(struct LINK_LIST));
```

but that modification is only local to the function ; once you get back to your calling function, that change is lost :

```
struct LINK_LIST *new_node;
init_link_list(new_node);
// Oops ! new_node's new value is lost !
```

You have a memory leak (the `malloc`'s result is lost) and `new_node` is not initialized. When you try to access `*new_node`, you access a random position in memory, hence core dumps.

There are a few possible corrections, the easiest is to discard your OK/ERROR return values and return either a non-null pointer if malloc succeeded, or NULL if it failed :

```
struct LINK_LIST *init_link_list(void) {
  struct LINK_LIST *new_link = malloc(sizeof(struct LINK_LIST));

  if (new_link==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory!!!");
    return NULL;
  }

  new_link->next = NULL;
  return new_link;
}
```

Then, code in insert becomes :

```
...
else {
  i = 0;
  do {
      struct LINK_LIST *new_node = init_link_list();
      // Note : here, should check whether new_node is NULL and deal with the situation
      new_node->next = link->next;
      link->next = new_node;
...
```

Comment: but `new_link` is redeclared!

Comment: @hyaocuk, no, `new_link` is not redeclared ; the one in `insert` is not the same as the one in `init_link_list`. They happen to have the same name, but that's coincidence (you can rename it in any of the 2 functions, if that helps you). I have added the code calling the new version of `init_link_list` in my answer ; I hope that helps understanding the point.

Comment: I see, I think I understand, but what I meant before was `int init_link_list(struct LINK_LIST *new_link) {
  struct LINK_LIST *new_link = malloc(sizeof(struct LINK_LIST));
` I think it's better to remove the argument

Comment: Your function prototype is wrong. Should be of LINK_LIST * type rather than int.